# Can i transforme from flexbox to grid

Tags: html, css

this was done with flexbox, but I want to replace it with grid. I know how to set up a grid, but I don't know how to prevent the element next to a resized element from changing height.

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="first">
          <div>1</div>
          <div (onClick)="expand">2</div>
          <div>3</div>
     </div>
      <div class="second">
          <div>4</div>
          <div>5</div>
          <div>6</div>
     </div>
</div>

.container{
  display:flex;
  gap:10px;
  width:100%;
}
.first, .second{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  gap:10px;
  width:100px;
}
.first > div, .second>div{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq7ze.png)

I want when I click on an item, the item should resize, but the item next to it should not change height. Can this be done with grid?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90RdJ.png)

Comment: Not possible with Css-grid.